# batch script not getting values when scheduled

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have this bat script:

```
copy "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Timbrature_Giornaliere_%date:~0,2%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~6,4%.csv
copy "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Prenotazione_Mensa_%date:~0,2%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~6,4%.csv
del "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv"
del "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv"
bye
```

When I run it manually it works.
When I run it on a scheduled task (using: whether user is logged on or not, run with the highest privilege), the copy command does not work (I should get the files with date at the end but the folder is empty when the task complete).
What is preventing the copy to work?

Comment: What does the history tab of the task scheduler tell you?

Comment: BTW, you have missed the closing doublequotes for the destinations.

Comment: What's `bye`? There is no such command in `cmd`...

Answer (score 0):

revisited the script and now it works:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('powershell get-date -format "{dd-MM-yyyy}"') do @set _date=%%#
copy "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Timbrature_Giornaliere_%_date%.csv
copy "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Prenotazione_Mensa_%_date%.csv
del "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv"
del "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @Compo is right: you missed two quotes.
Second: do you really need to invoke powershell from cmd to create a timestamp string? I think there could be two better approaches:

1. directly use a powershell script
2. save the string value of the current date in a variable in the batch script and reuse it

The first approach would look like this:

```
$currentDt = Get-Date -Format "{dd-MM-yyyy}"
cp "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Timbrature_Giornaliere_$currentDt.csv" -ErrorAction Stop
cp "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Prenotazione_Mensa_$currentDt.csv" -ErrorAction Stop
rm "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv","C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv"
```

Save it in a .ps1 file and launch it diretly from powershell.
The second approach (batch) instead would look like this:

```
@echo off
set current_date=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%
copy "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Timbrature_Giornaliere_%current_date%.csv"
copy "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\PRESENZE_MENSA\Prenotazione_Mensa_%current_date%.csv"
del "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Timbrature_Giornaliere.csv" "C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\CSV\Prenotazione_Mensa.csv"
```

Comment: **WARNING:** There's a typo : `$durrentDt` vs. `$currentDt`. `rm` is executed without checking for success of the previous operations - that's quite dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected the typo and add an `-ErrorAction Stop` on each copy operation to make it stop if one copy fails